# Getting date format in server side

Tags: c#, web-services, datetime, iis, format

I have a C# Web Service running on a Windows machine, and i have this code:

```
Details = tInfoRequestHistory.Select(i => new AppJsonDetails
                                {
                                    Type = i.PlatformUserId == null ? "Request" : "Response",
                                    Date = i.Date.ToString("D"),
                                    Time = i.Date.ToString("hh:mm tt"),
                                    Text = i.Comment,
                                }).ToArray()
```

And i'm receiving this JSON in my app:

```
{
    Date = "lunes, 12 de enero de 2015";
    Text = "402\\nGarcia\\n01/12/15 12:52 \\nBla bla";
    Time = "11:52 ";
    Type = Request;
}
```

As you can see i'm missing the PM/AM (in fact there is a blank space) in the node "Time" that is generated with this instruction i.Date.ToString("hh:mm tt")

If i execute my code in my development machine everything is working ok.

I'm using windows server 2012 and the last IIS 8.0 and i have just change the regional settings of my server to match my development machine so i'm reading in my server clock "12:00 PM"

I'm sure that this is some configuration i'm missing in the Server or in the IIS or maybe in the Web.config.

Any help or idea will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Well*, since you using [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) without any [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx), sounds like your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s [`AMDesignator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or / and [`PMDesignator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.pmdesignator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties are empty string.

I would suggest a use [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a  `IFormatProvider` like;

```
i.Date.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or change current culture that have *non-empty* `AMDesignator` and `PMDesignator` properties in your windows machine region settings.

Comment: My friend THANKS!! you are the best!!